# mySQL where clause with alternative

Tags: mysql

[image]I have a mysql query that should return a row incase it found a value, otherwise it should use a default value:
I mean, I will try to find a specific language to return the row, If this language is not found, the query should use a default specific language variable. 
(inside PHP code)
eg. $language=FR , the query should return the FR language row otherwise, should return the default EN language row

```
Select * from my_table where lang="$language"
```

I want to return the row of EN language as default row in case FR language (or any other language) not found.
How can I do this?

Comment: please share your schema and/or example input/output and table data.

Comment: what fields you really need? could you post table structure and data sample?

Comment: if you want to get the row of "EN" language, just use language="EN". but if you are looking for a specific row,  according to filters you didn't told us about, then we could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `case` and `order by`

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  table
WHERE lang = 
  CASE
    WHEN lang = 'FR' 
    THEN 'FR' 
    ELSE 'EN' 
  END 
ORDER BY lang = 'FR' DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: what is the difference of this query from "lang IN ('FR','EN')"

Comment: This query returns 2 rows when both FR and EN exist. It should return only FR (if found) otherwise returns EN row

Comment: @bourax thats y i have added limit 1 it will return only one row if record with FR exist it will return that row else row with EN will be returned

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid chokran ;)

Answer (score 3):

A neat trick :)

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from my_table where language="FR"
union all
select *  from my_table where language="EN" and FOUND_ROWS() = 0
```

The second query in the union is executed only if the first doesn't find a row.

Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

Comment: nice - never knew that!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a union, something like this

```
select * from 
(
  select 0 as is_default,* from my_table where language='FR'
  union all
  select 1,*  from my_table where language='EN'
) t
order by is_default
limit 1
```

Comment: Smart thinking definitely deserves +1

Comment: I got Error 1064 in SQL syntaxe !!

Comment: can't try it at the moment, but maybe I used the wrong quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use UNION:

```
Select topimage,botimage... from my_table where lang="FR"
UNION
Select topimage,botimage... from my_table where lang="EN"
```

Comment: this returns EN row, it should return FR row because it exists